# Changing ForeignKey's defaults in admin site

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin

I'd like to know how I can change the blank value of ForeignKey in admin site's forms. There blank is showed as "-----". I wanna replace it by a word.

Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Create custom ModelForm and override your field there, then, assign this form class to form option of ModelAdmin. Like this:

```
#forms.py
class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), empty_label=u'label')

class Meta:
    model = MyModel

#admin.py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = CustomForm
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ModelChoiceField's empty_label.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

Comment: Ok, thanks.

But I wanna do it in some forms of admin site. I don't know how I could get a specific field of a specific form using django admin.